# Why this is working? Swift (UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional>)

Tags: swift

```
protocol Property {}
protocol OptionalProtpery : Property {
        static func codeNilInto(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>)
    }

    extension Optional : OptionalProtpery {
        static func codeNilInto(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) {
            (UnsafeMutablePointer(pointer) as UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional>).memory = nil
        }
    }
```

I am interested in this statement `UnsafeMutablePointer<"Optional">`
Why we don't have an error for instance: "Optional generic type and requires arguments <...>". Since specific type (for instance UnsafeMutablePointer<"Optional"<"Int">>) is not specified right over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protocol Property {}
protocol OptionalProtpery : Property {
    static func codeNilInto(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>)
}

extension Optional : OptionalProtpery {
    static func codeNilInto(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) {
        (UnsafeMutablePointer(pointer) as UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional>).memory = nil
    }
}

var i = 1
let p = withUnsafePointer(&i) { (p) -> UnsafePointer<Int> in
    return p
}
print(p.memory) // 1

//Optional.codeNilInto(p) // error: generic parameter 'Wrapped' could not be inferred
// you have to specify generic parameter !!!
Optional<Int>.codeNilInto(p)
Optional<Double>.codeNilIntro(p)
// or what ever you want to express
```

so, because Optional is generic, you code is 'OK'. By the way, what do you expect your code does?